# SQL View where rows not mapped

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-view

Basically what I'm trying to figure out is,
Say I have

table 1`tbl1`

`ID | Name`

and table2`tbl2`

`ID | Name`

Then I have a mapping table `mt`

`ID | tbl1ID | tbl2ID`

Data really isn't important here, and these tables are examples.

How to make a `view` that will grab all the items in `tbl1` that aren't mapped to `mt`.

I'm using Microsoft SQL-server 2008 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW v_unmapped
AS
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl1
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  tbl1Id
        FROM    mt
        )
```